# Tracking Group Expenses in Excel: Pivot Table for Expense Matrix Calculation

Tags: excel, pivot, dax

I want to track expenses for myself and my friends using an Excel spreadsheet. I have a table structure that includes the date, amount, payer, split type, and names of individuals involved. I would like to create a matrix-like table that shows the amount owed between each person. I have already achieved this using complex formulas, but I am curious if it can be done using Pivot Tables, which are powerful and potentially easier to maintain.

**Table Structure:**

| Date | Amount | Paid By | Split Type | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16.05. | 4.99$ | Name 1 | Split Equal |  |  |  | ... |
| 16.05. | 10$ | Name 1 | Split Unequal by Percentage | 50% | 50% |  | ... |
| 18.05. | 10$ | Name 3 | Split Unequal by Amount | 2$ | 6$ | 2$ | ... |

**Goal:**
Create a matrix table that displays the amounts owed between individuals based on the provided table structure. The desired table will have names in the rows and columns, with the corresponding amounts owed displayed.

So for the above example, the desired result could look like this:

|  | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | - | - | 0.34$ |
| Name 2 | 6.66$ | - | 6$ |
| Name 3 | - | - | - |

**Question**

Is it possible to create the desired matrix table using Excel's Pivot functionality? I would appreciate any tips or guidance on how to approach this. If you can show me an example for one case (e.g., split unequal by amount), I can replicate it for the other cases.

**What I've Tried**

I have successfully achieved the desired result using formulas in a regular table. However, I would like to explore the possibility of using Pivot Tables. I have attempted to create a Pivot Table but encountered difficulties in aligning the names in the rows and columns. Once I solve this issue, the next step would be to calculate the correct values within the cells using measures and DAX formulas, but I'm unsure of the approach.

### Edit 1: Clarify the Result Matrix

As Jos stated, the result matrix maybe isn't that obvious unlike I thought, so I'd like to give one example:

*Name1* owes *Name3* `0.34$` - why?

- *Name1* pays `4.99$` and this should be split equally (thus, in particular, *Name3* owes *Name1* `1.66$`.
- *Name1* pays `10$`, however, this doesn't account to *Name3* since only *Name1* and *Name2* have to share this money
- *Name3* pays `10$` from which *Name1* ones him `2$`, *Name2* `6$` and *Name3* `2$`.

In sum, *Name3* owes *Name1* `1.33$` from the first payment, and *Name1* owes *Name3* `2$` from the third payment. This can be summarized by: *Name3* owes *Name1* `1.66 $ - 2$ = -0.33$` (which is the same as saying *Name1* owes *Name3* `0.33$`

Comment: Re "*I guess the way you get there should be pretty obvious*", not to me! Can you clarify one or two of the expected results you've given, for example the $0.34?

Comment: Yep sure, sorry. After revisiting it, I also think it's not that trivial. That's why I added one example :) I hope this helps in understanding